# VB.NET, Trying to add a DataGridView control and have accidentally changed my form's Me.name datatype to DataGridViewTextBoxColumn?

Tags: vb.net

Title, pretty much sums it up.
Trying to run suddenly gives the error Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30311 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn'.  \My Project\Till.Designer.vb    2362    Active

Line 2362 is Me.Name = "frmTill" and Me.Name is now supposedly WithEvents frmTill.name As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. I've no idea how this happened or how to reverse it!

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. When creating my DataGridView object, I called one of my columns Name, which I think overwrote the Me.Name used in defining the form and caused the datatype to change from `string` to `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`. However it happened, renaming the column to something else has fixed it.